# Adding a search facility to a Raspberry Pi hosted Website

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, apache

We have local valley news. It is created with Publisher and PDF versions are made available on the web see https://www.itchenvalleyparishcouncil.org.uk/itchen-valley-news/ I would like to set up a facility on a Raspberry Pi hosted website that would allow the set of PDF publications to be scanned. Happy to use some software to build an index the PDF's or Publisher documents at the same time that the PDF is made available.

Ideally Free.

Thanks

Comment: Can you program (preferably Python)?

Comment: Yes see https://github.com/KeithSloan?tab=repositories

Comment: I am sure that our resident Python guru @SteveBarnes can hep you better than I.  But, first, let's clarify your design. What happens with the search result? Is the user simply given a list of matching PDFs or do you want to display with the search term highlighted? If the former, it might be simpler to export as text files and search those. Although I am sure that Steve can recommend a Python module to process PDF. Take a look at https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/ and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-pdf-files-in-python/

Comment: I don't want to have to develop something. I am after a more canned solution. I already have too many projects that need completing.

Comment: Understood. But, if you clarify what the output should look like, then maybe we can help you to can it :-)

Comment: Not really bothered what the output looks like, just after a facility that would allow people to search for information and for them to told what month they are after. If it took them to a display of the info, so much the better